# how to insert a variable in JSON Path (Oracle PL SQL)?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

- I want to insert the variable nmbr_v instead of the value 4444
- I tried to put + around the variable but it doesn't work

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
nmbr_v number;
v_id number;
-- I want to insert the variable nmbr_v instead of the value 4444
cursor cur_nmbr is select id from tbl where json_exists(nmbr, '$[*]?(@ == 4444)');
begin
open cur_nmbr;
loop

fetch cur_nmbr into v_id;
exit when cur_nmbr %notfound;
dbms_output.put_line( 'id= ' ||v_id);
end loop;

close cur_nmbr;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON path has to be a text literal, so you can't (whether you use `+` as you said in the question, or the concatenation operator `||`, or built a variable with the complete path).

I believe you would need to use dynamic SQL, which you can implement here as a dynamic implicit cursor:

```
declare
  nmbr_v number := 4444;
  v_id number;
  cur_stmt varchar2(80);
  cur_nmbr sys_refcursor;
begin
  cur_stmt := q'^select id from tbl where json_exists(nmbr, '$[*]?(@.x == ^' || nmbr_v || q'^)')^';
  dbms_output.put_line(cur_stmt);

  open cur_nmbr for cur_stmt;
  loop
    fetch cur_nmbr into v_id;
    exit when cur_nmbr %notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line( 'id= ' ||v_id);
  end loop;

  close cur_nmbr;
end;
/
```

Now `cur_nmbr` is declared as a `sys_refcursor` instead of a static explicit cursor, and the cursor query is then built and supplied dynamically.

The statement construction uses [the alternative quoting mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA); the `q'^...^'` means that any single quotes appearing within that string don't need to be escaped.

The `cur_stmt` variable isn't strictly needed, but it's helpful to have it so you can output it for debugging; here it shows the output:

```
select id from tbl where json_exists(nmbr, '$[*]?(@.x == 4444)')
```

which is your original static cursor query.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=457c731fc415fe7e8b62d18210596b9f), including showing various invalid approaches and the errors they get.

If the `nmbr_v` value is being passed in then you might want to do some validation, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your help, just a small question what is the point of the letter 'q' in this line please  ```cur_stmt := q'^select id from tbl where json_exists(nmbr, '$[*]?(@.x == ^' || nmbr_v || q'^)')^'; ```

Comment: @dahi - I've added a note about that and a link to the docs.